# mingw32-make install "no rule to make target 'install'

Tags: cmake, codeblocks, allegro

I have an annoying problem, because i don't have any idea, what should I do. 
I want to extend my code::blocks program with allegro, and i found a really useful documentation (you can see here: https://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/606041), but i can't do the 12. step, because the "mingw32-make install" order give me a special error message: no rule to make target 'install'. 
I spent 2 hours to find the solution, but it was unsuccessful.

Any idea?
I appreciate the help.

Comment: Did you type `mingw32-make Install` (with an uppercase `I`) by mistake instead of `mingw32-make install`?

Comment: Yes, it is just a mistake. In the cmd, i wrote 'i'.